# Matlab's imimposemin function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I dont quite understand Matlab's `imimposemin` function described [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imimposemin.html). According to the documentation the function *modifies the grayscale mask image I using morphological reconstruction so it only has regional minima wherever binary marker image BW is nonzero*.

In the example that demonstrates the function, Mathworks creates a marker which is a black image with a small white square. According to the documentation `imimposemin` (if I undestand well) it should modify the array `mask` so it has local minima wherever `marker` is nonzero. In other words it should modify mask over that white square only and replace the corresponding values in `mask` of those pixels with the regional minimum.

However we see that almost every single pixel of `mask` has changed value and the image it self has become lighter. Why?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it should modify mask over that white square only and replace the corresponding values in `mask` of those pixels with the regional minimum.

This would create local minima at the places indicated by `marker`, but the image already had local minima elsewhere, which need to be removed.

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> modifies the grayscale mask image `I` using morphological reconstruction so it **only** has regional minima wherever binary marker image `BW` is nonzero.

That is, the output cannot have local minima outside those specified by `marker`. This means that the `mask` image must be modified to remove its local minima. This is accomplished by giving the pixels in `marker` the lowest possible value, and, propagating from there, pixels get either the value they already had, or the larger value from the neighbor. You should be able to draw a decreasing path from any pixel in the image to one of the pixels in `marker`.

This function is typically used in combination with the watershed, which segments the image based on local minima. By imposing your own local minima, you can force the seeds of the watershed algorithm.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks Chris! This is the bit i was missing. Removing local minima outside the marked region. And this is done by replacing the value of each pixel by something larger from its neighbours or keeping it the same. And yes, it is watershed I am trying to do, in Python. Your `PyDIP` package doesnt have something equivalent if I understand well

Comment: @Aenaon DIPlib has [`dip.SeededWatershed`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/segmentation.html#dip-SeededWatershed-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-uint--dip-dfloat--dip-uint--dip-StringSet-CL), which combines the minima imposition with the watershed algorithm, so you avoid creating that intermediate image. There's also [`dip.ImposeMinima`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/morphology.html#dip-ImposeMinima-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-uint-).